# how to save two objects of the same type in yacc union which appear at the same rule?

Tags: c++, yacc, abstract-syntax-tree

I am facing a problem in yacc union, it is, in short: I have declared a union like this

```
   %union{
         struct R{
         int col_no,line_no;
         int i;
         float f;
         char c;
         char* str;
            }r;
         class TreeNode * node;
       }
```

then In the grammar I have this rule:

```
assign_statment:expression_list ASSIGN expression_list
         {
           $<node>$ = rePositionAssign($<node>1,$<node>3,yylval.r.line_no, yylval.r.col_no);
    }
```

My question is: will this rule produce two diffrent `TreeNode*` objects or not?
And if it would give just the same object for the two `$<node>1` and `$<node>3`, Is there any technique to get two distnict objects each of which would represent a diffrent expressionlist node.

And the expression_list rule I do the following:

```
   expression_list: expression_list COMMA expr  
                {
                    $<node>$ = ast->addToLastRight($<node>1, ast->createNode($<node>3, 0, exprListNode));
              }
       |expr              
                 {
                      $<node>$ = ast->createNode($<node>1, 0, exprListNode);
                }
```

`ast` is an object of class `AST` which has the method

```
    TreeNode * createNode(TreeNode * left, TreeNode* right, NodeType nt);
```

to create a new node in the ast tree and connect it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what you do in your functions.  There are
separate instances of the union for each term, so `$<node>1` and
`$<node>2` refer to different instances of the *pointer*.
Whether they point to the same thing or not depends on what
you've put in them; yacc just copies the `union` when
appropriate.

If you have a pointer to dynamically allocated memory in the
`union`, you must have an action for every rule that has a term
which would receive the  pointer, and this action must either
delete it, or pass it on as `$<node>$`, or insert it into some
other object which will manage its memory.  It's not as
difficult as it sounds, but it does require some attention to
detail.

Comment: Thanks @James Kanaze, so

if the input file was :

t.i,x = 5,3; //equal to t.i=5; x=3

I would get two `TreeNode`.

Comment: @creativeCreative If your scanner returns two different `TreeNode`, you would get two different `TreeNode`.  `yacc` doesn't care; it just assigns the pointer returned from the scanner to the union.  But within a rule, each `$i` is a separate variable, as is `$$`.  (The `$i` variables disappear after the rule is reduced, so make sure you do any necessary memory management in them---copying the pointer into another object may be sufficient.)

Comment: @creativeCreative Also, of course: if your scanner returns a pointer to the same static instance of `TreeNode`, then all of the `$<node>i` will refer to the same `TreeNode`.